# Oracle Sessions

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We have session parameter defined in pfile to limit no of sessions. 
Where as in profile we have max_session parameter which is set to unlimited.
What is difference between two

Answer (score 1):

The initialization parameter `sessions` is the total number of sessions allowed in the database, that is the total number of concurrent connections. This is explained in [the Oracle Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams234.htm#REFRN10197).

Profiles on the other hand define limits for individual users. The `sessions_per_user` parameter governs how many concurrent connections the individual user can have open. The [Oracle SQL Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310) covers this.

Each connection uses resource: `sessions` is the ruling parameter and it must be set to a sensible value, because it controls how many connections are allowed. Leaving `sessions_per_user` as UNLIMITED means we don't care how many times an individual user connects to our database; whatever they do, the total number of connections cannot exceed the limit of `sessions` .

Answer (score 0):

The initialization parameter [SESSIONS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-52804B5A-164F-44F3-8980-F2593B58D807.htm#REFRN10197) is a limit for the entire database instance.  For example, you might set this value to prevent an application from creating a massive amount of connections instead of using a connection pool.  (Although in my experience we always end up increasing this parameter to a ridiculous value instead of changing the application.)

The profile setting [SESSIONS_PER_USER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF54282) limits the number of concurrent sessions for a specific user.  For example, you might set this to stop a specific user from creating a parallel job with a ridiculously high degree of parallelism.